# AngularJS: How to change the color property via toggle when css class does change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJS and have already found a lot of helpfull answers on this forum, however the following item is driving me nuts.

First of all, let me tell you what I want to do:
I do have an element, of which I would like to change the color property at runtime, but only when that particular element has the class 'active'.

Therefore, I have created a directive which looks like the following:

```
OfficeUIRibbon.directive('officeActiveStyle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$watch(function() {
            return element.attr('class');
          }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) { // Values will be equal on     initialization
              alert('Changed');
            }
          });
        }
    };
});
```

As far as my knowledge goes, this does watch the attribute class and the if check in their does make sure that the watch isn't triggered when the application is first launched.

Now, the class property of the element is being set by using the ng-click directive.

When I now execute the HTML, nothing happens. When I click the 'set active' link, the class is changed, but the directive doesn't show me an alert. (Why is that?). If I then change the class again, then the directive does show me an alert.

So, why, on the first click, the alert of the directive isn't triggered?

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zx6B46iuKil0ZnbCvwFo?p=preview) for better understanding.

Hopefully, someone can tell me what's wrong with this because it's really blocking my work.

Comment: How is it that the class attribute value changes, without AngularJS doing it? Because - the answer to this question is really 'you don't want to'.

Comment: alert in plunker fires for me in 2 different browsers. Not sure why you want to watch the class when the class is being changed by data that you already have access to. What is the higher level objective other than just an alert?

Comment: In the plunker there are 2 links. Clicking on them execute a function in the controller which does change a value. The element itself has a ng-class attribute on that value.  And indeed the alert does fire, but not when you click on any of the links for the first time. As from the second click the alert does show.

Comment: watching class makes no sense in the first place

Comment: Ok but I need to set the color of an element based on the class. If it's active color should be x otherwise y. But I cannot define the color in css since I don't know the color at css level. Only the controller does now.

Comment: Sounds like a job for that old-fashioned thing called CSS.

Comment: I don't know the color value in css. The controller does now the color value.

Comment: This question is a complete X-Y problem. You made `change color` so vague and now what seems like best approach isn't. Where do the color values come from and why aren't you focusing on them? This is a  classic case of an `X-Y problem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you don't need to use `directives` to make this work nice. You could use `ng-style`or just `$scope`like the following example will show you. This [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jyVlGkMqYD7AWFBmKfYa?p=preview) shows you, how easy make a "toggle" work in AngularJS by using `directives`.

```
var OfficeUIRibbon = angular.module('OfficeUIRibbon', []);

OfficeUIRibbon.directive('officeActiveStyle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$watch(function() {
               officeUiRibbonActiveHexColor = '#f700ff';
          });
        }
    };
});

/**
 * CSS Hex color holder
 * @type {string}
 * @global
 */
 var officeUiRibbonActiveHexColor = '#ff0000';

/**
 * Active holder
 * @type {boolean}
 * @global
 */
 var officeUiRibbonActiveToggle = false;

// Defines the AngularJS 'OfficeUIRibbon' controller.
OfficeUIRibbon.controller('OfficeUIRibbon', ['$scope', '$http', '$animate', function($scope, $http, $animate) {


    $scope.toggle = function () {
      officeUiRibbonActiveToggle = officeUiRibbonActiveToggle ? false : true; //switch active state
    }

    $scope.getStyles = function () {
      if (officeUiRibbonActiveToggle) {
         return officeUiRibbonActiveHexColor; 
      }
    }
}]);
```

HTML-Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="OfficeUIRibbon">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="OfficeUIRibbon">
    <div
         office-active-style=""
         style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: {{ getStyles(); }}">Dit is een demo</div>

         <a href="#" ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

### Solution 2

**Optional**: This is an other [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XerJgolQyZEg3VA4WboM?p=preview). This demo shows you, how easy make a "toggle" work in angularjs without using `directives`.

```
var OfficeUIRibbon = angular.module('OfficeUIRibbon', [])

OfficeUIRibbon.controller('OfficeUIRibbon', ['$scope', '$http', '$animate', function($scope, $http, $animate) {

    /**
     * Active state holder
     * @type {boolean} 
     */ 
    var active = false;

    /**
     * Holds css color hex code
     * @type {string}
     */
    var color = '#ff0000';

    /**
    * Check active scope
    */
    $scope.toggleShow = function () {
      active = !active; //switch true false in the coolest way ;)
    }

    /** 
    * Check active scope
    */
    $scope.giveColor = function () {
      if (active) { 
         return color;
      } 
    }
}]);
```

Your HTML-Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="OfficeUIRibbon">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="OfficeUIRibbon">
    <div office-active-style=""
         style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: {{ giveColor() }}">Dit is een demo</div>

         <a href="#" ng-click="toggleShow()">Toggle</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've lost the link to the chat. Any idea on how I reconnect?